# How to correct this angular forms issue?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, formgroups, angular-formbuilder

When I click on edit option First Time So I am able to see my field values. Then when I click on other row edit option  the field value of already clicked row is also getting updated by the value of the latest row which I am updating. I have Uploaded two images to understand the problem. What could be the solution for this ??

[image]

[image]

This  is My HTML :-

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-role let-editing="editing" let-ri="rowIndex">
          <tr [pEditableRow]="role" [formGroup]="updateRoleForm">
            <td>
              <p-cellEditor>
                <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                  <input type="text" formControlName="name"  pInputText maxlength="40">
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                  {{role.name}}
                </ng-template>
              </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td>
              <p-cellEditor>
                <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                  <input type="text" formControlName="description"  pInputText
                    maxlength="200">
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                  {{role.description}}
                </ng-template>
              </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td>
              <p-cellEditor>
                <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                  <p-dropdown formControlName="isModerator" [options]="isModerator"
                    optionValue="value" placeholder="Select" optionLabel="name" appendTo="body"></p-dropdown>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                  {{role.isModerator}}
                </ng-template>
              </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="!editing">
              <button pButton pRipple type="button" icon="pi pi-key" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text"
                (click)="showPermissionDialouge(role)"></button>
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="!editing">
              <button pButton pRipple type="button" icon="pi pi-bell" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text"
                (click)="showNotificationDialouge(role)"></button>
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="!editing" class="more">
              <div class="displayFlex flexJustifyEnd">
                <p-button (onClick)="toggleMenu(menu, $event,role)" styleClass="p-button-text"><i
                    class="icon icon-more-vertical"></i>
                </p-button>
              </div>
              <p-menu appendTo="body" pInitEditableRow #menu [popup]="true" [model]="items"></p-menu>
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="editing"></td>
            <td *ngIf="editing" style="text-align:center">
              <button pButton type="button" pSaveEditableRow icon="pi pi-check" class="ui-button-success"
                (click)="onRowEditSave(role)"></button>
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="editing" style="text-align:center">
              <button pButton type="button" pCancelEditableRow icon="pi pi-times" class="ui-button-danger"
                (click)="onRowEditCancel(role, ri)"></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ng-template>
```

This is My ts file:-

```
updateRoleForm!: FormGroup;

    private createForm() {
        this.updateRoleForm = this.fb.group({
          name: [null, Validators.required],
          description: [null, Validators.required],
          isModerator: [null, Validators.required]
        });
      }
    
    onRowEditInit(role: Role) {
        this.initializeUpdateRoleForm(role);
        const key = role.name;
        this.activeEditRows[key] = true;
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      }
    
    initializeUpdateRoleForm(role: Role) {
        this.updateRoleForm.patchValue({
          name: role.name,
          description: role.description,
          isModerator: role.isModerator
        });
      }
```

Comment: Can you try to reproduce it in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com)? Thanks.

Comment: As Yong mentioned, reproducing this on Stackblitz would be the best option. And from what I gather, it might be that you aren't completing the editing before moving onto the next row? (ie. leave some booleans `true` that shouldn't be)

Comment: Yes I am not completing the editing before moving onto the next row. Wait I am reproducing it on StackBlitz.